# VBS run Excel macro argument not optional

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBScript code that runs an Excel macro.

My VBA code:

```
Sub MyMacro(Name As String)

   'do something

End Sub
```

My VBScript code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\MyFile.xlsm'!MyMacro", "MyName"    

objExcel.Application.Quit

Set objExcel = Nothing
```

The error I get:

> Compile error: Argument not optional

How come I get this error if I do pass an argument?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you saved the VBScript and Excel file before you run it? `Argument not optional` means you didn't pass an argument where the macro needs one. The code you posted is correct (I tested it) and it runs without any issues. Please verify that the code is exactly the same you posted here and all files are saved before run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the module in which the macro resides, e.g.

```
"'C:\MyFile.xlsm'.Module1.MyMacro"
```

The following link doesn't explicitly say the macro must reside in a VBA module within Excel but I believe it must.

See the example code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: It should be `"'C:\MyFile.xlsm'!Module1.MyMacro"` with an `!` after the filename instead of `.` If you run it giving a path/filename. But that's not the issue. If `MyMacro` is not `Private` then `"'C:\MyFile.xlsm'!MyMacro"` works fine, no need to specify the module.